# Constructing membership site with joomla

Tags: joomla, membership, user-accounts

Hi i run Joomla site on htpp://www.deeptechtons.net and wanted to construct a membership based subscription where people pay to get premium articles.
Exactly the same as tutsplus site network.[ i think it is custom but some solution must be available for joomla]. I already looked into extensions directory nothing fits my purpose.
Some requirements i need are,

1.Custom Profile fields for members.
2.Any time un-subscribe from plan.
3.Simple interface to show plans available
4.Payment processor's support

Also how do i hide the articles for premium members from not showing in search results, both joomla and google.
Joomla has teensy, weensy setting that hides un categorized articles in search plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use 1.5, then Joomla 1.5 + JomSocial + AEC. I would also use K2 for the content because it would make filling your request about keeping content out of Google trivial. I wrote an upgrade to the K2 content display module that would allow you to leave all of your content as public and only display the intro text to non-registered users. Then you display the member content in a module that only displays to registered users. Very easy to maintain and implement.

Comment: "I wrote an upgrade to the K2 content display module that would allow you to leave all of your content as public and only display the intro text to non-registered users." Man that's exactly the kind of stuff i want. This would encourage registered members to opt for Memberships great :D i would test K2 first then let me ping again. Accepted as answer ,voted UP[oops 15 reputation, voting when i get some reputation]

Comment: All you need to do is set all of the member content to hide for the item view parameters of the category. Then install this module - http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension-specific/k2-extensions/13890. The module detects the item on the page you are displaying and allows you to display the content of that item in module position. Set it to display what ever content you want hidden and set the permissions to registered users. Let AEC handle registration and subscriptions.

Comment: Brent could you elaborate more, i did understand the K2 and aec part but not the Item and view part

Comment: The standard K2 Content module displays K2 content in a module position. In the module settings you select which items and how many of them to display. The modification I made is simple. You no longer select which modules to display. The module will now detect which item is already being displayed on the page, then display content for that item. So for category Member Content, you set the default Full Text parameter to be hidden. Then you add this module to the page and set it to display the full text, with the module permission to be registered users. Make sense? Try it, it's not bad to use.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running your website on Joomla 1.5 then [PayPlans](http://www.jpayplans.com) might be the better choice. It blends very well with JomSocial and your design. And yes, its very much customizable.